# Combining several database table together?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, join

I have two tables `tour_foreign`&`tour_foreign_residence` in database and want merger this two table together that get output from PHP code as following example:

My tables and values it:

[image]
[image]

I want get as output `tour_foreign.id = tour_foreign_residence.relation` :

> One-week tour of Istanbul_1   |   88888 & 99999 $ 112233 $ 445566   |   Three nights and two days   |   15:29
>   One-week tour of Istanbul_2   |   55555 & 66666 $ 77777   |   Three nights and two days   |   12:03
>   One-week tour of Istanbul_3   |   11111 & 22222 $ 33333 $ 44444   |   Three nights and two days   |   12:03

My try is this but it don't give to me what that I want in above:

```
$this -> db -> query("
    SELECT
           @rownum := @rownum + 1 rownum,
           tour_foreign.id, 
           tour_foreign.name, 
           tour_foreign_residence.name_re,  
           tour_foreign.term,
           tour_foreign.time_go, 
           tour_foreign.time_back,
           tour_foreign.type_of_vehicle
    FROM   tour_foreign 
           INNER JOIN tour_foreign_residence 
             ON ( tour_foreign.id = tour_foreign_residence.relation )
           JOIN (SELECT @rownum := 0) r
    WHERE  tour_foreign.name LIKE "%' . $find . '%" 
            OR tour_foreign_residence.name_re LIKE "%' . $find . '%"    
")
```

How can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try using [GROUP_CONCAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) to join the names from you tour_foreign_residence table

Comment: I can't test your actual query out but you can start by adding this to your SELECT statement: GROUP_CONCAT( tour_foreign_residence.name_re ORDER BY tour_foreign_residence.name_re SEPERATOR " $ ")

Comment: I add it after WHERE but get this error: `Error Number: 1064     

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GROUP_CONCAT( tour_foreign_residence.name_re ORDER BY tour_foreign_residence.nam' at line 18`

Comment: `
SELECT @rownum := @rownum + 1 rownum, tour_foreign.id, tour_foreign.name, tour_foreign_residence.name_re, tour_foreign.service, tour_foreign.date_go, tour_foreign.date_back, tour_foreign.term, tour_foreign.useradmin_submit, tour_foreign.date_submit  FROM tour_foreign INNER JOIN tour_foreign_residence ON ( tour_foreign.id = tour_foreign_residence.relation ) JOIN (SELECT @rownum := 0) r WHERE tour_foreign.name LIKE "%%" OR tour_foreign_residence.name_re LIKE "%%" GROUP_CONCAT( tour_foreign_residence.name_re ORDER BY tour_foreign_residence.name_re SEPERATOR " $ ")`

Comment: It must be added in the SELECT statement so something like this: SELECT tour_foreign.id, tour_foreign.name, tour_foreign_residence.name_re, tour_foreign.service, tour_foreign.date_go, tour_foreign.date_back, tour_foreign.term, tour_foreign.useradmin_submit, tour_foreign.date_submit, GROUP_CONCAT( tour_foreign_residence.name_re ORDER BY tour_foreign_residence.name_re SEPERATOR " $ ")  FROM...

Comment: ok, i changed but still have error: `Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SEPERATOR " $ ") FROM tour_foreign INNER JOIN tour_foreign_residen' at line 12`

Comment: `SELECT @rownum := @rownum + 1 rownum, tour_foreign.id, tour_foreign.name, tour_foreign_residence.name_re, tour_foreign.service, tour_foreign.date_go, tour_foreign.date_back, tour_foreign.term, tour_foreign.useradmin_submit, tour_foreign.date_submit, GROUP_CONCAT( tour_foreign_residence.name_re ORDER BY tour_foreign_residence.name_re SEPERATOR " $ ") FROM tour_foreign INNER JOIN tour_foreign_residence ON ( tour_foreign.id = tour_foreign_residence.relation ) JOIN (SELECT @rownum := 0) r WHERE tour_foreign.name LIKE "%%" OR tour_foreign_residence.name_re LIKE "%%"`

Comment: Oops, misspelled SEPARATOR, my mistake.

Comment: I misspelled part of it so replace the GROUP_CONCAT() function with this: GROUP_CONCAT( tour_foreign_residence.name_re ORDER BY tour_foreign_residence.name_re SEPARATOR " $ ")

Comment: I done `print_r` output query and get this case, please see here(it not what tah i want): http://pastebin.com/hTiN2VD3

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you are joining on @rownum, it might be messing with your result set. Try taking it out and see if it works.

Your inner join looks ok, except I have never seen it with the wrapped parens, but I suspect it will work as expected. To test your query you could remove the complicated where clause and just put something like where tour_foreign.id = 1.

Something like:

```
SELECT
    tf.*
FROM 
    tour_foreign AS tf
INNER JOIN
    tour_foreign_residence AS tfr
ON
    tfr.relation = tf.id
WHERE
    tf.id = 1
```

I implemented aliases for your longer table names (tf, and tfr) as they are easier to work with.

Comment: Not work this, it have error: `Error Number: 1051,

Unknown table 'tour_foreign',

SELECT tour_foreign.* FROM tour_foreign AS tf INNER JOIN tour_foreign_residence AS tfr ON tfr.relation = tf.id WHERE tf.id = 1`

Comment: @Nicole : Sorry, need to use the alias. I edited the sql to reflect the change.

Comment: I use it as: `$query = $this -> db -> query("
      SELECT
    tf.*
FROM 
    tour_foreign AS tf
INNER JOIN
    tour_foreign_residence AS tfr
ON
    tfr.relation = tf.id
WHERE
    tf.id = 1");` this is without error but it not has output?

Comment: I get out from query as (but your query not have output): `foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
    echo '<td>' . intval($row -> rownum + $offset) . '</td>';
       echo '<td>' . $row -> name . '</td>';}`

Comment: Can you just run the sql command from MySQL command line or (appears you are using PHPMyAdmin) interface? According to the schema you provided it appears you have at least 4 rows in the tour_foreign_residence table that should be returned.