# Combining two table with sql JOIN?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, join

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Combining several database table together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7814244/combining-several-database-table-together)

I want from two database table get output like this:

> One-week tour of Istanbul_1   |   88888 & 99999 $ 112233 $ 445566   |   Three nights and two days   |   15:29
>   One-week tour of Istanbul_2   |   55555 & 66666 $ 77777   |   Three nights and two days   |   12:03
>   One-week tour of Istanbul_3   |   11111 & 22222 $ 33333 $ 44444   |   Three nights and two days   |   12:03

These are my tables:

[image]
[image]

**Update:**

it give me this output: http://img708.imageshack.us/img708/2404/outputnz.gif but if i put in $find value "55555" for where output is as: http://img528.imageshack.us/img528/3576/outputnow.gif but i want out is as: http://img832.imageshack.us/img832/120/outputwant.gif . How is it?

```
$query = $this -> db -> query('
    SELECT
       @rownum := @rownum + 1 rownum,
       tour_foreign.id, 
       tour_foreign.name, 
       MIN(tour_foreign_residence.name_re) AS name_re, 
       tour_foreign.service, 
       tour_foreign.date_go, 
       tour_foreign.date_back, 
       tour_foreign.term,
       tour_foreign.useradmin_submit,
       tour_foreign.date_submit,
       GROUP_CONCAT( tour_foreign_residence.name_re 
                     ORDER BY tour_foreign_residence.name_re 
                     SEPARATOR " $ "
                   ) AS name_re_all
    FROM   tour_foreign 
      INNER JOIN tour_foreign_residence 
        ON ( tour_foreign.id = tour_foreign_residence.relation )
      JOIN (SELECT @rownum := 0) r
    WHERE  tour_foreign.name LIKE "%' . $find . '%" 
        OR tour_foreign_residence.name_re_all LIKE "%' . $find . '%"
    GROUP BY  tour_foreign.id ');
```

I get from above sql following error:

> A Database Error Occurred
>  Error Number: 1054
>
> Unknown column 'tour_foreign_residence.name_re_all' in 'where
>   clause'
>
> SELECT @rownum := @rownum + 1 rownum, tour_foreign.id,
>   tour_foreign.name, MIN(tour_foreign_residence.name_re) AS name_re,
>   tour_foreign.service, tour_foreign.date_go, tour_foreign.date_back,
>   tour_foreign.term, tour_foreign.useradmin_submit,
>   tour_foreign.date_submit, GROUP_CONCAT( tour_foreign_residence.name_re
>   ORDER BY tour_foreign_residence.name_re SEPARATOR " $ " ) AS
>   name_re_all FROM tour_foreign INNER JOIN tour_foreign_residence ON (
>   tour_foreign.id = tour_foreign_residence.relation ) JOIN (SELECT
>   @rownum := 0) r WHERE tour_foreign.name LIKE "%%" OR
>   tour_foreign_residence.name_re_all LIKE "%%" GROUP BY
>   tour_foreign.id
>
> Filename:
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\system\database\DB_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 330

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to group by something or the aggregate `GROUP_CONCAT()` will collect all rows into one:

```
GROUP BY  tour_foreign.id
```

Use:

```
$query = $this -> db -> query('
    SELECT
       @rownum := @rownum + 1 rownum,
       tour_foreign.id, 
       tour_foreign.name, 
       MIN(tour_foreign_residence.name_re) AS name_re, 
       tour_foreign.service, 
       tour_foreign.date_go, 
       tour_foreign.date_back, 
       tour_foreign.term,
       tour_foreign.useradmin_submit,
       tour_foreign.date_submit,
       GROUP_CONCAT( tour_foreign_residence.name_re 
                     ORDER BY tour_foreign_residence.name_re 
                     SEPARATOR " $ "
                   ) AS name_re_all
    FROM   tour_foreign 
      INNER JOIN tour_foreign_residence 
        ON ( tour_foreign.id = tour_foreign_residence.relation )
      JOIN (SELECT @rownum := 0) r
    WHERE  tour_foreign.name LIKE "%' . $find . '%" 
        OR tour_foreign_residence.name_re LIKE "%' . $find . '%"
    GROUP BY  tour_foreign.id ');
```

Comment: See here: http://pastebin.com/DJndg1Et name_re there is only 1 no all!?

Comment: `name_re` is supposed to get the first of the id for every group? Or what?

Comment: name_re is here: `tour_foreign_residence.name_re, ` in my sql code in first post. did you see it?

Comment: Try my edit. The `[name_re]` will now have the minimum of those ids. The `[name_re_all]` will have all of them, separated by `$`.

Comment: Thanks, it give me this output:http://img708.imageshack.us/img708/2404/outputnz.gif  but if i put in `$find` value "55555" for where output is as: http://img528.imageshack.us/img528/3576/outputnow.gif but i want out is as: http://img832.imageshack.us/img832/120/outputwant.gif . How is it?

Comment: Use `name_re_all` for output, not `name_re`.

Comment: Please see my update in first post. ?

Comment: @Alicia: Don't change the SQL code, change the PHP code that you use for output. Print the `name_re_all`. This is not a table column but a calculated field - you can see it in SQL in :`GROUP_CONCAT(...) AS name_re_all`.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `GROUP BY` clause at the end of the SQL statement.

Comment: I use from code @ypercube. See here: http://pastebin.com/DJndg1Et name_re there is only 1 no all!?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.name, GROUP_CONCAT(b.name_re ORDER BY b.name_re SEPARATOR " & "), a.term, a.time_go 
FROM tour_foreign a INNER JOIN tour_foreign residence b
ON a.id = b.relation
GROUP BY a.name
```

I'm just learning SQL so i picked up your problem as an exercise. Hope it works.

Comment: I use from code @ypercube. See here: http://pastebin.com/DJndg1Et name_re there is only 1 no all!?(how should use from your code `a` & `b`?)

Comment: a and b are aliases for tour_foreign and tour_foreign_residence.