# Error: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want for a row that get of database table forch it for echo each a but have following error:

```
$query = $this -> db -> query('
    SELECT
       @rownum := @rownum + 1 rownum,
       tour_foreign.id, 
       tour_foreign.name, 
       MIN(tour_foreign_residence.name_re) AS name_re, 
       tour_foreign.service, 
       tour_foreign.date_go, 
       tour_foreign.date_back, 
       tour_foreign.term,
       tour_foreign.useradmin_submit,
       tour_foreign.date_submit,
       GROUP_CONCAT( tour_foreign_residence.name_re 
                     ORDER BY tour_foreign_residence.name_re 
                     SEPARATOR " "
                   ) AS name_re_all
    FROM   tour_foreign 
      INNER JOIN tour_foreign_residence 
        ON ( tour_foreign.id = tour_foreign_residence.relation )
      JOIN (SELECT @rownum := 0) r
    WHERE  tour_foreign.name LIKE "%' . $find . '%" 
        OR tour_foreign_residence.name_re LIKE "%' . $find . '%"
    GROUP BY  tour_foreign.id ');

foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
echo $row->name_re_all //thisoutput is: 11111 22222 33333 44444 ...
    foreach ($row->name_re_all as $val) {
        echo $val . '<br>';
    }
}
```

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
>
> Filename: core/Loader.php(679) : eval()'d code
>
> Line Number: 86

Comment: Which foreach statement is line 86? If it's the latter try using explode($row->name_re_all, ' ') before the foreach loop

Comment: This line: `foreach ($row->name_re_all as $val) {`

Answer (score 1):

[Foreach](http://php.net/foreach) is used to iterate trough an array, you're passing a string as a parameter

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but if you want to ask how to change the code so it works - the comment by @Belinda on your post will help you. You haven't really provided much information, but it looks like you want to turn the string into an array and then print it. Makes no sense if it's just that, but anyway - check Belinda's comment

Comment: @NicoleSpears is it really *your* code? Or just a code you're seeing for the first time?

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel This code is certainly [not new](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7817818/combining-two-table-with-sql-join)