# Group_CONCAT search

Tags: php, mysql, join, group-concat

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Combining several database table together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7814244/combining-several-database-table-together)

I have following query and want done where with each value that is in `$find` for `name_re_all`, how is it in my query?

**For example:** `name_re_all` is as:

> `ROW 3:` 11111 22222 33333 44444
>  `ROW 2:` 55555 66666 77777
>   `ROW 1:` 88888 99999 112233 445566

If value `$find` was `11111` show all values row 3: `11111 22222 33333 44444`
Or
If value `$find` was `66666` show all values row 2: `55555 66666 77777`
Or
If value `$find` was `33333` show all values row 3: `11111 22222 33333 44444`
Or
If value `$find` was `778899` show all values row 1: `88888 99999 112233 445566`
Or
and `...`

```
$query = $this -> db -> query('
            SELECT
               @rownum := @rownum + 1 rownum,
               tour_foreign.id, 
               tour_foreign.name,
               tour_foreign.airline,
               MIN(tour_foreign_residence.name_re) AS name_re, 
               tour_foreign.service, 
               tour_foreign.date_go, 
               tour_foreign.date_back, 
               tour_foreign.term,
               tour_foreign.useradmin_submit,
               tour_foreign.date_submit,
               GROUP_CONCAT( tour_foreign_residence.name_re 
                     ORDER BY tour_foreign_residence.name_re 
                     SEPARATOR "، "
                   ) AS name_re_all
            FROM   tour_foreign 
              INNER JOIN tour_foreign_residence 
            ON ( tour_foreign.id = tour_foreign_residence.relation )
              JOIN (SELECT @rownum := 0) r
            WHERE  tour_foreign.name LIKE "%' . $find . '%" 
            GROUP BY  tour_foreign.id 
            HAVING name_re_all LIKE "%' . $find . '%"'
            );
```

My tables in database:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please post the table structure and some (representative) example data.

Comment: I put tables in post, Please see they.

Comment: yuck, this [mysterious query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7817818/combining-two-table-with-sql-join)  again! Who are all these people after the same query?!

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel - this is just a example

Comment: @WallStreet And where is this 11111, 22222, 33333 in this example data? I'm happily willing to answer questions, but if I wanted to solve riddles I'd go somewhere else.

Comment: NOpe. this is new aaccount instead of one temporarily suspended because of low-quality contributions.

Comment: @Wall Street this very same query has been posted from at least 3 different accounts (Alicia Cibrian, Nicole Spears, Jennifer Anthony, and this), with the same level of broken english. Please, just try all the answers you were given, I can't believe no one worked; in that case, something is wrong with the question then, and reposting it all over again without significant changes doesn't help you.

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel Maybe everyone in Istanbul (?) got the same homework assignment?

Comment: Then they have to DO their homework, using KNOWLEDGE got in classes. Homework is intended to be done by pupil, not some other people.

Comment: Please help me for resolved this issue instead of discussing about other issues... !!!

Comment: @Damien Pirsy - these users not for me, ... !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: This query will never work, because you're using `'` single quotes to quote both the string as a whole and the params inside. Put `"` double quotes on the outside and single `'` quotes for the params.

Comment: @Johan - Thanks, It is right. It work true if i remove `WHERE  tour_foreign.name LIKE "%' . $find . '%"` from sql, How can use `WHERE... OR HAVING name_re_all...`

Comment: Use as this `HAVING name_re_all LIKE '%" . $find . "%' OR name LIKE '%" . $find . "%'"` is true(without use `where`)?

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel Professional jobs are intended to be done by professionals. Then why are we sharing information here for people who actually get paid to do it themselves? I don't see why students shouldn't be helped while professionals should.

Answer (score 0):

As a variant: wrap this query into subquery -

```
SELECT * FROM (
  your query...
) t
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('11111', name_re_all);
```

**EDIT:**
You should use the subquery!

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT
     @rownum := @rownum + 1 rownum,
     ...
     ...
     ...
     GROUP_CONCAT( tour_foreign_residence.name_re 
           ORDER BY tour_foreign_residence.name_re 
           SEPARATOR "، "
         ) AS name_re_all
  FROM   tour_foreign 
    INNER JOIN tour_foreign_residence 
  ON ( tour_foreign.id = tour_foreign_residence.relation )
    JOIN (SELECT @rownum := 0) r
  WHERE  tour_foreign.name LIKE "%' . $find . '%" 
  GROUP BY  tour_foreign.id 
--  HAVING name_re_all LIKE "%' . $find . '%"
) t
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('11111', name_re_all)
```

Comment: See here that is my change sql and error that get: http://pastebin.com/sHaPwebk

Comment: Subquery! You cannot use field alias in WHERE the same clause.

Comment: No, this way not work and not it what that i want. i should use of `%$find%` instead of '11111'

Comment: Did you know other way for resolved this issue? did can not done it with php?

Comment: There is another way, but this variant is working. Create a simple table and try to work with it.